# Image not showing from Django rest api in Reactjs

Tags: javascript, python, reactjs, django, django-rest-framework

data i've got from server:

```
[
    {
        "id": 29,
        "name": "atlas",
        "image": "/media/images/images-4.jpeg",
        "price": 67473,
    },
]
```

in React:

```
//...code
console.log(this.props.img); //>>> /media/images/images-4.jpeg
//...code
<img src={this.props.img} alt='image' width='100%'/>
//...
```

in Django:

I think there is no problem in django. I made a template and tried to show image, and it worked.

So, how do I show image in React ?

Comment: api returning only path of image .so append base url before image like "https://urdomain.com"+this.props.img

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Api returning only path of image .so append base url before image link like below

```
<img src="https://urdomain.com{this.props.img}" alt='image' width='100%'/>
```

or in django you have to send full url in image value like below

```
[
    {
        "id": 29,
        "name": "atlas",
        "image": "https://urdomain.com/media/images/images-4.jpeg",
        "price": 67473,
    },
]
```

so no need to append base url

```
 <img src="{this.props.img}" alt='image' width='100%'/>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to add you domain to the image path

```
const BASE_URL = "your base here" 

<img src={`${BASE_URL}${this.props.img}`} alt='image' width='100%'/>
```