# How do I access and view the image present in my Laravel's storage folder in a React form?

Tags: reactjs, laravel, forms

I have few images in my storage folder(laravel), I want to view them in my React data table. Apparently it only displays the path name of the image.

Answer (score 0):

First you have create symbolic link

```
php aritsan storage:link
```

this will create `shortcut storage` folder in `public folder`

so you can access url

```
https:://urdomain/storage/filename
```

Here i assume your images of files exist in `storage/app/public`.If your files contain in any subfolder then it should be

```
https:://urdomain/storage/subfoldername/filename.extension
```

ref:https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/filesystem#the-public-disk

[image]

[image]

Also in reactjs if you are  getting json response like this

```
{
        "id": 23532,
        "name": "john",
        "image": "images/image.jpeg",
       
    },
```

then you might need to append baseurl

```
 <img src="https:://urdomain/storage/{image}" alt='image' width='100%'/>
```

Also you refer this answer :
[Image not showing from Django rest api in Reactjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67832406/image-not-showing-from-django-rest-api-in-reactjs/67832437#67832437)